# One Api request for an image works but a copy of it in another HTML file in the same folder doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
  menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
});

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=";
var api_key = "Q6LCLptEevXBK9pvwj1GeEsPbM4mmv6ywTmfw0Nc";

req.open("GET", url + api_key);
req.send();

req.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if (req.status == 200 && req.readyState == 4) {
    var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    document.getElementById("title").textContent = response.title;
    document.getElementById("date").textContent = response.date;
    document.getElementById("pic").src = response.hdurl;
    document.getElementById("explanation").textContent = response.explanation;
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  background: darkred;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-gem {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.btnclick {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f77062;
  color: #fff;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #4837ff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #f77062;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #131313;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}


/* Main Content CSS */

.main {
  background-color: #131313;
}

.main__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  align-items: Left;
  justify-self: Left;
  margin: 100px;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #131313;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.main__content {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.main__content h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-20deg, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.main__btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
  padding: 14px 32px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4837ff;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.main__img--container {
  text-align: center;
}

#main__img {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}


/* Mobile Responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90vh;
  }
  .main__content {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
  .main__content h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .main__content h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .main__content h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 3rem;
  }
  .main__content h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .main__content p {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .main__btn {
    padding: 12px 36px;
    margin: 2.5rem 0;
  }
}


/* Services Section */

.services {
  background: #131313;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.services h1 {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #ff8177 0%, #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%, #b12a5b 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.services__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.services__card {
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 525px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%), url('/images/pic3.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.services__card:before {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.services__card:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9) 100%), url('/images/pic4.jpg');
}

.services__card h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 30px;
}

.services__card p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 30px;
}

.services__card button {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f77062;
  position: absolute;
  top: 440px;
  left: 30px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.services__card button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.services__card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.075);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .services {
    height: 1600px;
  }
  .services h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 12rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .services {
    height: 1400px;
  }
  .services h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .services__card {
    width: 300px;
  }
}


/* Footer CSS */

.footer__container {
  background-color: #141414;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#footer__logo {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.footer__links {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer__link--wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.footer__link--items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 160px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer__link--items h2 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.footer__link--items>h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer__link--items a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.footer__link--items a:hover {
  color: #e9e9e9;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}


/* Social Icons */

.social__icon--link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.social__media {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.social__media--wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}

.social__icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 240px;
}

.social__logo {
  color: #fff;
  justify-self: start;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.website__rights {
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .footer__links {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  #footer__logo {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .website__rights {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .footer__link--wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .social__media--wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .footer__link--items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>HTML CSS Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body style="background-color:#131313;">



  <div class="grid-container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__container">

        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar__menu">
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Coming Soon</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/tech.html" class="navbar__links">Coming Soon</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Coming Soon</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>



  <div class="main">
    <div class="main__container">
      <div class="main__content">
        <h1>Starfield</h1>
        <h2>Explore Images from NASA</h2>
        <p>By Nick</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main__content">
    <div class="main__container">
      <div class="item2">
        <h1>NASA Astronomy Picture Of The Day</h1>
        <h2 id="title" /h2>
          <h3>Date: <span id="date"></span></h3>
          <img id="pic" src="" alt="NASA Picture Of The Day" width="30%">
      </div>
    </div>



    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HTML CSS Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
</head>
<style>

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
 
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  
  text-align: Left;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>

<body style="background-color:#131313;">


<div class="grid-container">
  
  <div class="item1">
<div class="main">
      <div class="main__container">
        <div class="main__content">
<h1>Starfield</h1>
          <h2>Explore Images from NASA</h2>
          <p>By Nikunj Patel</p></div>  
  
        </div>
      </div>


</div>

<div class="main__content">
<div class="main__container">
<div class="item2">
          <h1>NASA Astronomy Picture Of The Day</h1>
    <h2 id="title"></h2>
    <h3>Date: <span id="date"></span></h3>
    <img id="pic" src="" alt="NASA Picture Of The Day" width="100%">
    <p id="explanation"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

So why does the first html produce an image and the second doesnt but both return the Error:
(**Both HTMLs use the same CSS and Js files**)
"{
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 680,
"colno": 56
}"
i want to use the formatting of this second html file instead of the first and i was surprised no image was produced

Comment: Your second document is missing the `#mobile-menu` element, so running that same excat JS code gives me an error in the `menu.addEventListener` line. If I remove those lines, the image shows up fine, and I don't see any further errors.

Comment: That worked thanks